# Clang error: Cannot compile builtin function yet

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I am compiling the linux kernel code which also contains the gcc libraries (separately added) with clang. I am stuck at the following error:

```
gcc/unwind-dw2.c:1336:3: error: cannot compile this __builtin_init_dwarf_reg_size_table yet
```

'__builtin_init_dwarf_reg_size_table' is a builtin function in gcc. I could not find enough material on the net to solve this error. However I have found the reference to this function in clang as:

```
BUILTIN(__builtin_init_dwarf_reg_size_table, "vv*", "n")
```

at location prebuilt_include/clang/include/clang/Basic/Builtins.def. But I don't understand what is its purpose.

Any heads-up regarding the error would be really helpful.

Edit: While looking around to understand how clang works, I found another reference to this builtin function in CGBuiltin.cpp file in function 'EmitBuiltinExpr'. But could not understand how can I use it to solve my problem. Is there any good source to understand all this?

Comment: It may be a clang bug. Are you able to compile `unwind-dw2.c` with a different clang/gcc version?

Comment: Yes, with gcc 4.9 it is getting compiled.

Comment: Can you please tell what does this error "can not compile yet" means? And if it is a clang bug, how to confirm it and report about it?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply @Shashank shekhar Dubey. The error seems to indicate the builtin is unsupported by clang on your target - please see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clang code suggests that, the error `cannot compile this <something> yet` means that `<something>` is a construct that is not supported by Clang on the target architecture.

In this case,`init_dwarf_reg_size_table` is a GCC builtin, which isn't fully supported on all Clang targets. Inspecting GCC's [`builtins.def`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/builtins.def) can confirm that `init_dwarf_reg_size_table` is a GCC extension.

As a workaround, you may have to compile with GCC instead, or with a more recent clang version which supports this builtin, if any.

---

Following clang code, the `cannot compile this <something> yet` message is printed by the `ErrorUnsupported` function in [`CodeGenModule.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenModule.cpp):

```
/// ErrorUnsupported - Print out an error that codegen doesn't support the
/// specified stmt yet.
void CodeGenModule::ErrorUnsupported(const Stmt *S, const char *Type) {
  unsigned DiagID = getDiags().getCustomDiagID(DiagnosticsEngine::Error,
                                               "cannot compile this %0 yet");
  std::string Msg = Type;
  getDiags().Report(Context.getFullLoc(S->getLocStart()), DiagID)
    << Msg << S->getSourceRange();
}
```

In [`CGBuiltin.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/CGBuiltin.cpp), the builtin is expanded and `ErrorUnsupported` is called if the the `initDwarfEHRegSizeTable` target hook failed:

```
  case Builtin::BI__builtin_init_dwarf_reg_size_table: {
    Value *Address = EmitScalarExpr(E->getArg(0));
    if (getTargetHooks().initDwarfEHRegSizeTable(*this, Address))
      CGM.ErrorUnsupported(E, "__builtin_init_dwarf_reg_size_table");
    return RValue::get(llvm::UndefValue::get(ConvertType(E->getType())));
  }
```

`initDwarfEHRegSizeTable` is defined in [`TargetInfo.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/TargetInfo.cpp). To be honest, I don't fully understand yet under what conditions it fails (which also depends on the target architecture).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @valiano, I will try to understand and report the problem with clang, if required.